# How to do not in ( ) concept in Azure data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have given an expression like

```
not(in(["FIX","ANGELA","ZERO","$0","INSTALLED",toString(null())],upper(CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER))in(["FIX","ANGELA","ZERO","$0","INSTALLED",upper(CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER)))
```

in my filter Stream.

Here iam getting wrong no of rows filtered because nulls also been taken out.
My other idea was to do a "Conditional Split" ,in conditional split i mentioned

```
in(["FIX","ANGELA","ZERO","$0","INSTALLED",toString(null())],upper(CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER))in(["FIX","ANGELA","ZERO","$0","INSTALLED",upper(CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER))
```

Now when i see no of rows in where the condition is false :Am getting the right no of rows using Conditional Split .

So I thought of including toString(null()) as :

```
not(in(["FIX","ANGELA","ZERO","$0","INSTALLED",toString(null())],upper(CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER))in(["FIX","ANGELA","ZERO","$0","INSTALLED",toString(null()),upper(CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER)))
```

in filter .But that giving me 0 rows .

How to get the same output as conditional split False condition in filter ? not(in()) is not working in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate the scenario in my local.

**Input used**

[image]

**Dataflow**

[image]

**Expression for filter1**

[image]

**Code used in filter expression**   `in(["FIX","ANGELA","ZERO","$0","INSTALLED"],upper(CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER))||isNull(CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER)`

**Explanation**

Using `toString(null())` into `in()` was not checking for null values and returning only matching records except null/empty value. I have removed `toString(null())` from `in()` and used  `||` with `isNull()` and it gave below result including null records.

**Result/Data preview**

[image]

To get not matching records you can use `not()` as mentioned below.    `not(in(["FIX","ANGELA","ZERO","$0","INSTALLED"],upper(CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER))||isNull(CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER))`

**Result/Data preview**

[image]